# $f(x)=y$ while $g(y)=x$; Is it possible to find two not reverse functions that behave such at least for a given set of inputs and outputs?

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics

I want to know if it is possible to program such a code that could determine two distinguish, not inverse, functions, say $f$ and $g$, that is true for the below statements at a given input and output diapason?

for the diapason $(x_1,x_2,...,x_{100}), (y_1,y_2,...,y_{100})$ both statements below should be true:

1) $f(x)=y$

2) $g(y)=x$

If you already know such functions, please share with me. My aim is to find such two functions, with or without using programming.

EDIT: I have to inform that this idea if successful, will be used for app activation. The scheme will be like this:

1) App is downloaded from the web-site.

2) App creates a unique fingerprint for the computer (fp)

3) fingerprint is sent to activation server

4) activation server generates a key for the fp.    ser(fp)=key

5) key is sent back to app

6) app verifies if key is valid. app(key)=fp.

The trick here must be that functions app and ser must be different and not inverse

Comment: What domains do you want these functions to be defined on? (And to clarify: you want the two functions *not* to be inverse functions, yet "act like" inverse functions on these particular inputs, right?)

Comment: yes exactly, I want not inverse two functions to act like inverse on a particular inputs. Domains integers fit better, fractions (like 4.442) are also suitable, but irrationals dont fit my purpose

Comment: I think about overlapping parts of two exponential equations, but don't know how to find them

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, for example, $$f(x)=g(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)\cdots(x-100)+x$$

For every $x=1,2,3,4, \cdots, 100$, we have $f(x)=g(x)=x$, because there is a zero in the product. However these functions are clearly not each others inverse.

Comment: I don't see a solution here. For example, if x=-5, then f(x)=-4; g(-4)=error

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question. But the inverse domain is $0 < x< 100$. Also, I edited $g(x)$ to make it defined for all real $x$.

Comment: So $x=2$ then $f(x)=4$, $g(4)=2$. And if $x=6$ then $f(6)=36$ and $g(36)=6$.

Comment: Thank you whythagoras, it returns the inputs and outputs, however isn't sqr(x) the inverse of sqrt(y) ?? I understand that you added x+1 part, but it doesn't work for me. I need a single formula for each equation.

Comment: @HasanA. I changed it to something completely different. It is now a single formula. Furthermore, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is the same formula.

Comment: if there is a zero in the product, its simply f(x)=g(x)=x which is useless because f(x)=x and g(x)=x and f(x)=g(x).

What I need is f(x)=y and g(y)=x where f≠g

Comment: @HasanA. There is only a zero in the product if $x=1,2,3,4, \cdots, 100$. At exactly these points they are each others inverse, and nowhere else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25422/discussion-between-hasan-a-and-wythagoras).